# Using an "IF" statement on a "With" Statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to set up a "with" statement in vba code in Access, but the form that the "With" is referencing could change. Is there a way to do this without rewriting the code in the "with" statement twice?
it seems like I could do something like this:

```
If FooVarible = true then
    with forms!form1
else
    with forms!form2!subForm1
endif
    'have code here
end with
```

but there is no way that would compile.

Comment: *there is no way that would compile* - why not? If you use a proper `With .. End With` and reference the form with proper syntax it will work. For variable forms, create a Sub procedure and pass the form as an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variable:

```
Dim frm as Object
If FooVarible = true then
    Set frm = forms!form1
else
    set frm = forms!form2!subform1.form
endif
With frm
    'have code here
end with
```

Comment: This would be good, but I need to reference the form as a subform. I have edited my question to show this

Comment: Did you try `Set frm = forms!form2!subForm1` in the Else?  Did it not work?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that you can reference a subform with a form variable. I had to modify it a little and use `set frm = forms!form2!subform1.form`

Answer (score 3):

If `FooVariable` can be a precompiler constant then you can do this:

```
#Const FooVariable = False

Sub Test()

#If FooVariable Then
    With Forms!Form1
#Else
    With Forms!Form2
#End If
        'with block contents
    End With

End Sub
```

Likely not what you were after, but good to know still. Once compiled, VBA only sees this if `FooVariable` is `True`:

```
Sub Test()

    With Forms!Form1
        'with block contents
    End With

End Sub
```

And this, if `FooVariable` is `False`:

```
Sub Test()

    With Forms!Form2
        'with block contents
    End With

End Sub
```

Notice that the compiler never ever sees an incomplete `With` block.

Comment: This was the closest to what I was trying to do, but I probably should have been trying something along the way shown in Scott Craner's answer.

Comment: To be fair, likely not. Precompiler directives are applied *before* the code is parsed and processed - the precompiler constant(s) used in a precompiler directive cannot contain values that are only possibly known at run-time.